# How to Force Tensorflow to Run under float16?

Tags: json, tensorflow, keras

I am building up a sequential model by Keras with a custom activation function by defining a new class written by keras' tf backend and some tf's tensor operators themselves. I put the custom activation function in ../keras/advanced_activation.py.

I intend to run it using float16 precision. Without the custom function, I could use the following to choose between float32 and float16 easily:

```py
        if self.precision == 'float16':
            K.set_floatx('float16')
            K.set_epsilon(1e-4)
        else:
            K.set_floatx('float32')
            K.set_epsilon(1e-7)
```

Yet when involving the custom function into my model, it seems tf persists in float32 even when I chose float16. I understand that tf is run under flat32 by default, so my questions are:

1. There are also several built-in activation functions in the same file, how does Keras make them run under float16 so that I might be able to do the same? There is a tf method tf.dtypes.cast(...), can I use it in my custom function to force tf? There is no such a cast in those build-in functions.
2. Alternatively, how can I force tf to run under float16 directly by using Keras with tf as the backend?

Many thanks.

Comment: As a dirty workaround (or a way to debug it further) I might recommend tf.dtypes.cast() everytime custom function is applied. If not, it would probably be usefull if you describe your custom function in a bit more details. Is it pure TF or does it involve calling C++?

Comment: It is purely written in tf. For example, one segment looks like `inputss = tf.where(tf.math.logical_and(tf.greater(orig, 0), tf.less(orig, 0.25)), 0.25 / (1+tf.exp(-self.sharp*((inputss-0.125)/0.25))), inputss)` I think I will try cast, yet do you know in which way I will be able to tell if the cast is applied in my function, that is, which tf variable can I use to invoke a conditional operation of applying the cast or not?

Comment: Use `tf.constant` to wrap these constants like 0.125 and 0.25 in your desired `dtype`. TF might be upcasting to `float32` because of the default `dtype` for these.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer by debugging. The lesson is that

First, tf.dtypes.cast(...) works.

Second, I can specify a second argument into my custom activation function to indicate the data type of the cast(...). The following is the associated code

Third, we do not need tf.constant to indicate the data type of those constants

Fourth, I conclude that adding a custom function in custom_activation.py is the easiest way to define our own layer/activation, as long as it is differentiable everywhere, or at least piece-wisely differentiable and has no discontinuity at junctures.

```py
# Quadruple Piece-Wise Constant Function
class MyFunc(Layer):


    def __init__(self, sharp=100, DataType = 'float32', **kwargs):
        super(MyFunc, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.supports_masking = True
        self.sharp = K.cast_to_floatx(sharp)
        self.DataType = DataType

    def call(self, inputs):

        inputss = tf.dtypes.cast(inputs, dtype=self.DataType)
        orig = inputss
        # some calculations
        return # my_results

    def get_config(self):
        config = {'sharp': float(self.sharp), 
                  'DataType': self.DataType}
        base_config = super(MyFunc, self).get_config()
        return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape
```

Thanks @y.selivonchyk for your worthy discussion with me, and @Yolo Swaggins for your contribution.